# Touch Keyboard in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I browsed the web for a simplified keyboard for a project running on windows mobile, but I could not find anything good, so I tried to create one myself.

The basic problem encountered, related to which control use to realize the "keys", was: I need a control that:
- is clickable
- can contain text
- DOES NOT TAKE THE FOCUS

I made some attempt, and I found that the LinkLabel seems to be exactly what I need: it works.

Now, the question is: is that a good idea to use the LinkLabel to realize a touch screen keyboard, or this is the wrong approach? 
I would like to avoid developing all the application with this keyboard, and then find some trouble when it will be "too late".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly the "right" approach is to create an actual SIP (there's a [sample in the WinMo SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158734.aspx)).  Anything else and you have to deal with the focus issues you're already seeing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did not know that to create a custom SIP was possible!
I will follow your suggestion.